# Error in translating claims during crawl

Tags: crawling, claims

We are facing an issue indexing all the new content in an sharepoint farm (2016).
the error reported crawling the content is the following

```
[Microsoft.CrawlerFlow-10da182d-bd83-4b33-b590-cb18c80284cc] Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionHelper : Evaluation failure detected:    Operator          : ClaimsConverter PartialUpdate    Operator type     : ClaimsConverter    Error id          : 0    Correlation id    : 2df52d0f-52b3-4695-ade2-fb7f3a92d4c6    Partition id      : 0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b    Message           : Value was invalid.  Parameter name: sddlForm  System.ArgumentException: Value was invalid.  Parameter name: sddlForm    
 at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier..ctor(String sddlForm)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Processing.Security.ClaimsEncoder.Encode(ClaimsCollection claims, ICollection`1 allowAces, ICollection`1 denyAces)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Processing.Security.AbstractClaimsConverterProducer`1.ProcessRecord(IRecord r)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithTryCatch(IRecord record)
```

We suspect a malformed claims for the ACL for the object: we've found several malformed login and we have removed from the site without success.
I've a few questions

- is there any way to debug the value that throws the error?
- has anyone seen this error on the crawl?

We are aware of a similar error in setting up the sharepoint on an workgroup envinroment, but the search is working just fine

thanks

Answer (score 0):

We've finally determined the problem. a user with a different claim of the form

c:0).t||

i suspect the c element was the problem together with claim value since I've only saw for built in group and without issuer
as referenced in
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx

removed the users, the crawl get rid  of the error

luckily we had another web application in the crawl source that worked correctly and we were able to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
I have also
Value was invalid.  Parameter name: sddlForm
no direct error more than in the search service.

And it was our tests with different claims account that was the problem.
Removed the account and group with wrong cliams and it worked for me as well.